# Excel VBA open workbook and copy content

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a VBA that should ask user for file, then copy the content of the first sheet (Sheet name is not the default and contains a space) .. After that I need to delete specific columns .. From the rows I need to delete the rows that contains specific text (Case intensive)

All I can do now is load the file, but don't know how to copy the data to the active worksheet!!

```
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please Choose the RTCM File", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls (*.xls),")
''
If FileToOpen = False Then
MsgBox "No file specified.", vbExclamation, "Duh!!!" ' Notification that nothing is chosen
Exit Sub
Else ' Load the file, copy the first sheet and paste it in active sheet ...

End If
```

Comment: there have to be several examples of this on SO. I just searched and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455979/load-and-copy-excel-table-on-a-workbook-to-another-sheet-on-another-workbook) was the first result... though no answer in the question, the question itself has syntax you can use to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. This code will paste data in the sheet that is already active. you can replace Activesheet with Sheets("Sheetname") if you want to paste data in a specific sheet.

I have assumed that the data being pasted will only be from column A to column Z, please change it as required.

```
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please Choose the RTCM File", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls (*.xls),")

If FileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No file specified.", vbExclamation, "Duh!!!" ' Notification that nothing is chosen
    Exit Sub
Else ' Load the file, copy the first sheet and paste it in active sheet ...
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z65536").ClearContents
    Workbooks(FileToOpen).Activate
    lrow=Workbooks(FileToOpen).Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(65536,1).End(xlUp).Row
    Workbooks(FileToOpen).Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z" & lrow).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
```